# How do I access objects in a UITableViewCell in a custom method?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

### Edit: This post is kinda long so the end question is copied here:

> So obviously it is not checking the cell I am clicking, it is checking a
>   new cell that it is creating.  How would I go about checking the cell
>   that is clicked, and checking the content that is in that specific
>   cell (i.e. checking the text of that cell's label).

So in InterfaceBuilder I have a prototype cell, and I do the following code to create a number of cells ina  uitableview

```
//tableview datasource delegate methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return cellIconNames.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cellIconName = [cellIconNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSString *cellIconImageName = [[self cellIconImages] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.rightLabel.text = [cellIconNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.carrierImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIconImageName];

urlString = [cellButtons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 88);
[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(startCarrierSite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:button];

return cell;
}
```

So basically what I did is made an imageview, a label, and a seethrough button on each cell, and made the respective images and labels say different things according to an array.

The button I have in each cell points to the same selector, startCarrierSite:

This is the method for startCarrierSite

```
-(IBAction)startCarrierSite:(CustomCell *)cell;{

UILabel *rightLabel = (UILabel*) [cell.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *labelText = rightLabel.text;

if(labelText == @"Aetna"){
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.aetna.com"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is check the label of the cell, and if the .text of that label is equal to a certain string, I run the code for opening safari and blah blah blah, thats not the issue.

The issue is that I can't seem to check the labels in a cell.  The current way I am trying to do this is by running the action with the argument of CustomCell (which is a child of the UITableViewCell class).

This works and the cell is checked when you click it, but then I go to check the text of the label and it crashes.  I'm getting the error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds for empty array'

So obviously it is not checking the cell I am clicking, it is checking a new cell that it is creating.  How would I go about checking the cell that is clicked, and checking the content that is in that specific cell (i.e. checking the text of that cell's label).

EDIT (ADDING IN UPDATED METHOD):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell.urlString isEqualToString:@"Aetna"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.aetna.com"]];
}else if([cell.urlString isEqualToString:nil]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
    }

}
```

Comment: So your labels are showing the correct text? And the crash occurs in your -(IBAction)startCarrierSite:(CustomCell *)cell method?
Also, something doesn't seem right in how you are getting the label in your startCarrierSite method. I think you should just be saying cell.rightLabel instead of getting the first subview of the cell and type casting it. Are you even sure that the object at index 0 in cell.subviews is in fact a UILabel?

Comment: As an aside, why use a button in the contentView at all? Can't you just populate your table view cells from your data source and use the delegate to detect selection and take the necessary action?

Comment: I didn't know there was such a method gerald, guess thats just my novice programming :/ and yes I tried just doing rightLabel.text but that didn't work because I only defined it when I created the cells in the seperate method so it couldnt access those labels.  I am going to try Martol's answer and then come back

Comment: Yeah take a good look at UITableViewController and UITableView documentation. Also, UITableViewDelegate. It's not a small topic but very important to understand. So much functionality is built into these classes that you will use constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this UITableViewDelegate method:

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

From there you can access the cell with `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

**EDIT**

Also, do not compare strings with `yourString == @"someString"`.

Use `[yourString isEqualToString:@"someString"]`.

**EDIT 2 **

Add a property to your CustomCell

`@property (nonatomic) NSString *urlString;`

Set the property when you are creating the cell, and then in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, do this;

`CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Now the URL is simply `cell.urlString`.

Comment: I had tried that method, but i could not figure out how to read what was on the label from that.  I get that  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] will give me the cell I am working with, but how do i use that information to check the text of the label

Comment: Also, @Martol1ni I got rid of the buttons all together, I was unaware that you could just check for selection of the rows guess thats just my novice programming :/

Comment: Well, since you have made a custom tableviewcell, I would suggest to add a property to that called urlLabel. Then you can get the cell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and go to the url. check my updated answer.

Comment: Right, in CustomCell I have already defined it as "rightLabel"  but I can't seem to check that against anything.  I've basically tried to write something along the lines of CustomCell.rightLabel But that didn't work because that just accesses the class.

Comment: Okay Im working with your updated answer right now, let me get back to you

Comment: @Martol1ini I updated the Original Post at the bottom with my new method for doing this, but when I click the tableviewcell still does nothing.

Comment: @Martol1ini and the problem doesnt seem to be finding the URL although Im not sure if thats right, but even when i just put a [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL :[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com]]; just to make sure, Its not doing that.  So I have a feeling its something with the cell not even being checked for clicks (selections) and I'm not sure why